# In controller in angular js how to use console.log($window.result) to print data on screen

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the data from javascript object using below method in another page.I want to use this data to print on html page using angular js....Below is snippet of code I am using.

```
app.controller('tableCtrl', function($scope,$http,$window) {
    console.log($window.result);
     });
```

But it is not working

Comment: Try console.log($window) it would be sufisant i think

Comment: I want data to print on html page                                                         <div class="table"  ng-controller="tableCtrl">

<table border="1">

   <tr>

<tr ng-repeat="a in resultObject">
<td ng-repeat="column in cols">{{a[COLUMN_NAME]}}</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
</div>

Comment: `console.log()` will not print on the html page but in the console.

Comment: Do as Debasish suggested - $window.document.write(result);

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$window.document.write(result);
```

Comment: Still not able to work it out.Can you please help?.........................                                                app.controller('tableCtrl', function($scope,$http,$window) {
 $window.document.write(result);
 $scope.resultObject= $window.result;
    }

Answer (score 0):

will overwrite current document and write your result

```
$window.document.write(result);
```

if you want it in any of you html page include below snippet

**in Html**

```
<div ng-controller="tableCtrl">
    <span ng-bind="result"></span>
</div></code>
```

**in tableCtrl**

`$scope.result = result;` //whatever your result is